# Asymptotics of the Steenrod algebra / $s$-partitions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, partitions

Recall that an [$s$-partition](https://oeis.org/A000929) is a partition of a natural number $n$ such that each part is of the form $2^r-1$. By a fundamental theorem of Milnor, the number $p_s(n)$ of $s$-partitions of $n$ counts the dimension of the mod-2 [Steenrod algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steenrod_algebra) in degree $n$. I'm interested in the asymptotics of the function $p_s(n)$, as well as related functions for the odd-primary Steenrod algebras.

**Questions:**

1. Does the number of $s$-partitions $p_s(n)$ grow subexponentially in $n$?
2. If so, are there effective constants $p_s(n) \leq C_\epsilon (1+\epsilon)^n$?
3. What about the dimension of the odd-primary Steenrod algebras?

The OEIS page ([here's the link again](https://oeis.org/A000929)) leads to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019001003003?via%3Dihub) which gives an asymptotic formula for $\ln p_s(n)$, and all the terms are indeed sublinear in $n$, except possibly for the term involving a handicrafted function $W(z)$, whose growth I don't know how to estimate.

As for the odd-primary Steenrod algebras, Milnor showed that for $p$ an odd prime, the dual Steenrod algebra at the prime $p$ is the tensor product $P(\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots) \otimes E(\tau_0,\tau_1,\tau_2,\dots)$ where $deg(\xi_i) = 2p^i - 2$, $deg(\tau_i = 2p^i - 1)$, and $P, E$ denote polynomial and exterior algebras respectively, over $\mathbb F_p$. So counting the dimension reduces to a combinatorial partition problem of a similar flavor.

Comment: But even the number of all partitions is subexponential.  $p_s(n)$ grows as $\exp(c(\log n)^2)$.

Comment: Oh wow. Duh, of course! So I guess that leaves at most the effective bounds as a potentially interesting question...

Comment: The end of Theorem 2 in that paper says that $W(z)$ is bounded on the real line.

Comment: @MTyson Ah, thanks. I misread the bound $|y| \leq M$ (with $y = \Im z$) as $|z| \leq M$.

Answer (score 3):

My original answer, below the horizontal rule, was based on a misunderstanding.  I'm preserving it so that the comments make sense.

For a fixed odd prime $p$, the generating function for the corresponding partitions is
$$ \frac{\prod_{i\ge0}(1+x^{2p^i-1})}{\prod_{i\ge1} (1-x^{2p^i-2})}.$$
@Dvitek in the comments explains nicely why we want the $2p^i-1$ parts to appear at most once while the $2p^i-2$ parts can be repeated arbitrarily often.

For instance, for $p = 3$ the first 30 coefficients (from $n=1$) are
$$1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 5, 4.$$

There's a variant of the Frobenius problem here: $x^{19}$ is the highest power with coefficient 0.  In other words, 19 is the largest positive integer that cannot be made with parts 1, 5, 17 appearing at most once and parts 4 and 16 with no restrictions.  For $p=5$, I verified that the last 0 occurs for $n=39{,}047$.  For $p=7$, I believe the corresponding number is $659{,}108{,}891$.  (If that's an interesting value to find in general, I can explain my thinking.)

---

A near(ish) miss on (3) that's too long for a comment but might still be helpful as more than a cautionary tale.

I put the generating function
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x) \prod_{p,i} (1-x^{2p^i-2})(1-x^{2p^i-1})}$$
into Mathematica, with odd primes $p$ and exponents $i \ge 1$. (The $(1-x)$ factor handles the $i=0$ case of $(1-x^{2p^i-1})$.)  The sequence begins
$$ 1,1,1,2,3,3,3,5,7,8,8,11,15,17,18,23,30,35,37,45$$
which matches [OEIS A035362](https://oeis.org/A035362). That sequence has a much simpler description: partitions with parts $4k$ or $4k+1$.  Why should that be the same?

Fortunately, before thinking too much about the connection, I computed more terms and realized that, in fact, the sequences do not match.  The first discrepancy happens at $n=28$.  The parts for the partitions counted here are everything of the form $4k$ or $4k+1$ up to 25, but not 28, which is a part for the OEIS description.  That is, 28 is the smallest positive multiple of 4 that cannot be written as $2p^i-2$ for some prime $p$ and integer $i \ge 0$.

Back to your question, the asymptotics of the partitions you care about are bounded above by the partitions with parts of the form $4k$ and $4k+1$.  The OEIS page includes an asymptotic expression for those given by Vaclav Kotesovec.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're varying $p$ in the product and fixing $i$.  Shouldn't it be the other way around to compute the dimensions of the mod $p$ dual Steenrod algebra?

Comment: In addition, it seems like your generating function does not handle the difference between the polynomial and exterior algebras.  I think the exterior algebra terms should have a plus sign, not a minus sign, and go in the numerator.

Comment: To be completely explicit, it seems like you should have one generating function for each odd prime $p$ whose coefficients are the dimension of the appropriately-graded piece of the mod $p$ dual Steenrod algebra.  That g.f. $d_p(z)$ should satisfy $$d_p(z) = \frac{\prod_{i \ge 0}\left(1+x^{2p^i-1}\right)}{\prod_{i \ge 1}\left(1-x^{2p^i-2}\right)}.$$

Comment: @dvitek Thanks, I didn't understand that $p$ is fixed.  I did allow $i$ to vary, but only put that in the text, not the formula.  For your explicit generating function, why do the $\tau_i$ terms each appear at most once, while the $\xi_i$ terms can appear with repetition?  I.e., why isn't the generating function $$\frac{1}{\left(\prod_{i\ge0}(1-x^{2p^i-1})\right)\left(\prod_{i\ge1}(1-x^{2p^i-2})\right)}?$$

Comment: The $\tau_i$ terms appear at most once because they live in an exterior algebra, not a polynomial algebra like the $\xi_i$ terms.  In an exterior algebra the square of any element is zero (and in this particular case we don't have any funny characteristic-2 business to worry about either) so the $\tau_i$ appear at most once.

Comment: @dvitek Thanks.  For $p=3$, the generating function you gave has coefficients 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2 starting from $n=0$.  Does 0 make sense for $n=19$ in the algebraic context?  As partitions, that comes come the inability to assemble a partition of 19 from distinct parts $\{1,5,17\}$ and potentially repeated parts $\{4,16\}$.

Comment: Looks right to me, and $n = 19$ is the last zero coefficient.  I think that for all $d_p(z)$ you have only finitely many zero coefficients in the power series.